# Skip the leading and trailing spaces when finding tag by text with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Previously I used `req = soup.find("td", string = "tags text")`(just example) method to find elements by its text, but in this case the tags string has some spaces before and after the text.
Tag is like the below:

```
<dt>              I am text               </dt>
```

How should I ignore the leading and trailing spaces?
If I want to use the previous method, I have to write: `req = soup.find("td", string = "              I am text               ")`, but I think there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function in the `text=` parameter of `.find()` function (or `string=`):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   
html_doc = '''<dt>Other text</dt>
<dt>              I am text               </dt>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

dt = soup.find('dt', text=lambda t: 'I am text' == t.strip())

print(dt)
```

Prints:

```
<dt>              I am text               </dt>
```